# PDO related database errors

Tags: php, mysql, linux, pdo

After changing server configuration. Updated MYSQL and PHP . I'm getting different SQL errors like this one:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id =
>   '759'' at line 1
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I have added `$this->dbo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);` , that results in code errors.

I haven't changed anything in the code so it can't be synthax errors?

UPDATE:
    function loadAssoc($values = false) {

```
            // Execute statement
            ($values) ? $this->statement->execute($values) : $this->statement->execute();

            // Return associative array
            return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

I get the error PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on the line that use execute.

In my cpanel it says: linux, php 5.3.21, mysql 5.5.28(just upgraded to this one) thought that would fix the problem

And like I stated earlier everything was working before my server update :S

Comment: Show an example of a full query, please.

Comment: Show the 'code errors' when trying to enable buffered queries with PDO

Comment: The first error has nothing to do with PDO - *you* have composed the *syntactically incorrect* query.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php):

> If this attribute is set to TRUE on a PDOStatement, the MySQL driver will use the buffered versions of the MySQL API. If you're writing portable code, you should use PDOStatement::fetchAll() instead.

It seems that - for whatever reason - your updated PDO extension was linked against a mysql api that doesn't support buffered queries.

Your existing code is using buffered queries so it will fail. The only solution without changing the code itself would be:

- install the mysql client library that supports buffered queries
- link PDO against this library

---

To further help you I need additional information about which OS you are using and which versions of MySQL, PDO, PHP...

Comment: function loadAssoc($values = false) {

    // Execute statement
    ($values) ? $this->statement->execute($values) : $this->statement->execute();

    // Return associative array
    return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }   I get the error PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on the line that use execute. I think it could be that the PDO is linked to a wrong mysql api(from the only answer here). I'm going to look into that and return with my versions of mysql,php and pdo

Comment: In my cpanel it says: linux, php 5.3.21, mysql 5.5.28(just upgraded to this one) thought that would fix the problem

Comment: I would ask a question on cpanel support. (If you haven't already)

Comment: I will try that aswell. I contacted my hosting and they have been working on it all day aswell . I'm going to try cpanel aswell! Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome. Would be nice if you can post the solution if you'll find it. Good luck!